# About limit sequence in mysql

Tags: mysql

There are some script to verify the limit about one sequence.

for example

one table, with huge information, with INT ID ( auto increment )

how I verify If my sequence are so close from the limit of this column ?

Comment: Get `MAX(column)` value and compare it with maximal value for column's datatype.

Comment: No my friend, in this case I would like a solution to monitor the use of sequence , because they have limits in INT, you know.

Comment: I cannot understand both your need and your problem.. sorry.

Comment: I got..


I understand.
but if you are not a DBA it is difficult to understand.
but basically I'm setting up a monitoring to check which tables and sequences are reaching the maximum number allowed by a sequence column of INT.

Comment: In MySQL you may create some service table which will store monitoring data, and event procedure which will be executed periodically (for example, each hour) and will gather the information about table name, PK column name, column datatype, allowed maximal value and actual maximal value per PK AI. At any moment you may look into this table.

Comment: sys.schema_auto_increment_columns